# Получить связанные данные из 3 таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть 3 таблицы в БД.

```
MODELS
`MOD_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,`MOD_MFA_ID` smallint(6) ,`MOD_CDS_ID` int(11)

DESIG
`CDS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL, `CDS_TEX_ID` int(11) NOT NULL

TEXT
`TEX_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,`TEX_TEXT` varchar(1200)
```

Как мне получить данные параметр `TEX_TEXT` из третьей таблицы (TEXTS), если взаимосвязь такая:
Из таблицы MODELS параметр `MOD_CDS_ID` => параметр из таблицы DESIG `CDS_ID`
А параметр из таблицы DESIG `CDS_TEX_ID` = параметру из третьей таблицы TEXTS `TEX_ID`

То есть получить нужно такие данные:
Из таблицы MODELS => `MOD_CDS_ID`
Из таблицы DESIG => `CDS_ID` = `MOD_CDS_ID`, `CDS_TEX_ID`
Из таблицы TEXTS => `TEX_ID` = `CDS_TEX_ID`, `TEX_TEXT`

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
select * from TOF_MODELS 
JOIN TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS ON TOF_MODELS.MOD_CDS_ID = TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_ID 
JOIN TOF_DES_TEXTS ON TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_TEX_ID = TOF_DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID 
WHERE TOF_MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID = 647
```

Выводит 0 строк

Comment: оба join'а на left join поменяйте, похоже в базе "битые" ссылки.

Comment: Да, так вроде бы выводит правильно. А как такой запрос сделать рабочим - он напрочь вешает базу))
SELECT TOF_MODELS.MOD_ID, TOF_MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID, TOF_MODELS.MOD_CDS_ID, TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_ID, TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_TEX_ID, TOF_DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID, TOF_DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT FROM TOF_MODELS INNER JOIN TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS ON TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_ID = TOF_MODELS.MOD_CDS_ID INNER JOIN TOF_DES_TEXTS ON TOF_COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_TEX_ID = TOF_DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID WHERE TOF_MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID='.$id.' ORDER BY TOF_DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT

Comment: Индексы у вас есть какие-нить?

Comment: Да, проиндексировал некоторые поля и все стало работать. Спасибо. Измените комент в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь на самом деле вопрос не "как получить связанные данные", потому что ответ на этот вопрос банален - разумеется, джойн. И на этот вопрос автор сам уже ответил.

А вопрос у него, на самом деле, "почему у меня этот вопрос возвращает ноль строк". И ответ на этот вопрос тоже очевиден - потому что базе нет соответствующих записей.

Проверять себя можно руками. Выбираем

```
select * from TOF_MODELS WHERE TOF_MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID = 647
```

и получаем (или не получаем) список айди. дальше подставляем этот список в следующую таблицу. И так далее. Алгоритм простой как 2 копейки, никакое стаковерфлоу для него не нужно. Нужно просто верить своим глазам и действовать сообразно здравому смыслу.

Comment: select * from TOF_MODELS WHERE TOF_MODELS.MOD_MFA_ID = 647 выводит 106 строк

Comment: И может все тупить из-за огромного количества записей? Таблица DESIG  имеет около 6 млн. строк.